# Translate Makefile into CMakeLists; Cannot load shared library

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, shared-libraries

I have my own C++ library and I'm changing how it's being built (transitioning from a basic Makefile to CMake).

I also have a few C++ examples that make use of this library.

If I build the library using the Makefile, the examples run just fine.
If I build using the CMake-generated Makefile, the library appears to be built just fine, but the examples will fail with `error while loading shared libraries: libfpthread.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

## Building with CMake

```
$ cmake . -G 'Unix Makefiles'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads

$ make
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads -B/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/CMakeFiles /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads'
make -f CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads'
cd /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target fpthread
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads'
make -f CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads'
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/nvrecovery.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC -DENABLE_PROFILING -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP -DNDEBUG -DSSE_SUPPORT -Dfpthread_EXPORTS -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util  -fPIC  -g -O0 -msse2 -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/nvrecovery.cpp.o -c /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/nvrecovery.cpp
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xthread.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC -DENABLE_PROFILING -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP -DNDEBUG -DSSE_SUPPORT -Dfpthread_EXPORTS -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util  -fPIC  -g -O0 -msse2 -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xthread.cpp.o -c /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/xthread.cpp
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/libdthread.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC -DENABLE_PROFILING -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP -DNDEBUG -DSSE_SUPPORT -Dfpthread_EXPORTS -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util  -fPIC  -g -O0 -msse2 -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/libdthread.cpp.o -c /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/libdthread.cpp
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/logger.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC -DENABLE_PROFILING -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP -DNDEBUG -DSSE_SUPPORT -Dfpthread_EXPORTS -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util  -fPIC  -g -O0 -msse2 -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/logger.cpp.o -c /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/logger.cpp
[ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/real.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC -DENABLE_PROFILING -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP -DNDEBUG -DSSE_SUPPORT -Dfpthread_EXPORTS -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util  -fPIC  -g -O0 -msse2 -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/real.cpp.o -c /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/real.cpp
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xmemory.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC -DENABLE_PROFILING -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP -DNDEBUG -DSSE_SUPPORT -Dfpthread_EXPORTS -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util  -fPIC  -g -O0 -msse2 -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xmemory.cpp.o -c /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/xmemory.cpp
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xrun.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC -DENABLE_PROFILING -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP -DNDEBUG -DSSE_SUPPORT -Dfpthread_EXPORTS -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util  -fPIC  -g -O0 -msse2 -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xrun.cpp.o -c /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/xrun.cpp
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/prof.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC -DENABLE_PROFILING -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP -DNDEBUG -DSSE_SUPPORT -Dfpthread_EXPORTS -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util  -fPIC  -g -O0 -msse2 -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/prof.cpp.o -c /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/prof.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libfpthread.so
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libfpthread.so -o libfpthread.so CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/nvrecovery.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xthread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/libdthread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/logger.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/real.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xmemory.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/xrun.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fpthread.dir/src/prof.cpp.o -ldl -pthread 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads'
[100%] Built target fpthread
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/CMakeFiles 0
```

#### `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(fpthread)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

file(GLOB src relative ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*.cpp")
add_library(fpthread SHARED ${src})
target_include_directories(fpthread
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/heaplayers
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/heaplayers/util
)
target_link_libraries(fpthread
    Threads::Threads
    ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
)

add_definitions(-g)
add_definitions(-O0)
add_definitions(-DNDEBUG)
#add_definitions(-DDEBUG)
add_definitions(-msse2 -DSSE_SUPPORT)
#add_definitions(-DCHECK_SCHEDULE)
add_definitions(-DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC)
add_definitions(-DENABLE_PROFILING)
#add_definitions(-DGET_CHARACTERISTICS)
#add_definitions(-DLAZY_COMMIT)
add_definitions(-DLOCK_OWNERSHIP)
#add_definitions(-DPAGE_DENSITY)
#add_definitions(-DTRACING)
#add_definitions(-D'CUSTOM_PREFIX(x)=grace\#\#x')

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

message("source files:")
message(${src})
message("")
```

## Building with the *old* Makefile

```
$ make -f Makefile.old 
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -fPIC -g -DNDEBUG  -msse2 -DSSE_SUPPORT  -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC  -DENABLE_PROFILING  -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP  -D'CUSTOM_PREFIX(x)=grace##x'  -m64 -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers -I/home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/include/heaplayers/util /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/libdthread.cpp /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/xthread.cpp /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/xrun.cpp /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/real.cpp /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/prof.cpp /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/logger.cpp /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/xmemory.cpp /home/joaomlneto/Documents/GitHub/fpthreads/src/nvrecovery.cpp -o libfpthread.so -ldl -pthread
```

#### `Makefile`

```
CXX = g++ -std=gnu++11
SRCS=$(wildcard $(PWD)/src/*.cpp)
INCLUDE_DIRS = -I$(PWD)/include -I$(PWD)/include/heaplayers -I$(PWD)/include/heaplayers/util

TARGET_X64 = libfpthread.so
TARGET_X86 = libfpthread32.so
TARGETS = $(TARGET_X64) $(TARGET_X86)

CXXFLAGS  = -shared -fPIC -g
CXXFLAGS += -DNDEBUG # -DDEBUG/-DNDEBUG: enable/disable debugging
CXXFLAGS += -msse2 -DSSE_SUPPORT # Enable SS2 Support TODO automatic detection!
#CXXFLAGS += -DCHECK_SCHEDULE # Check deterministic schedule
CXXFLAGS += -DDETERM_MEMORY_ALLOC # TODO document
CXXFLAGS += -DENABLE_PROFILING # Enable execution profiling and print statistics at the end
#CXXFLAGS += -DGET_CHARACTERISTICS # Get some characteristics about running
#CXXFLAGS += -DLAZY_COMMIT # TODO document
CXXFLAGS += -DLOCK_OWNERSHIP # TODO document
#CXXFLAGS += -DPAGE_DENSITY # TODO document
#CXXFLAGS += -DTRACING # TODO document
CXXFLAGS += -D'CUSTOM_PREFIX(x)=grace\#\#x' # TODO document

CXXFLAGS32 = $(CXXFLAGS) -m32 -DX86_32BIT
CXXFLAGS64 = $(CXXFLAGS) -m64

LIBS = -ldl -pthread

.PHONY: default all x64 x86 clean

default: x64

all: x64 x86

x64: $(TARGET_X64)

x86: $(TARGET_X86)

$(TARGET_X64): $(SRCS) Makefile
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS64) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(SRCS) -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(TARGET_X86): $(SRCS) Makefile
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS32) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(SRCS) -o $@ $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS)
```

## Comparing generated objects

### Sizes

Sizes differ slightly.

```
$ file fpthread_*
fpthread_cmake.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=69aaa475c964666aad9fb04f9cb278042ef0c367, not stripped
fpthread_make.so:  ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=71178ef39a4e22eb3f8e3cae9210033c18eae3d3, not stripped

$ ls ./fpthread_* -lA
-rwxrwxr-x 1 joaomlneto joaomlneto 1100184 Apr  9 14:39 ./fpthread_cmake.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 joaomlneto joaomlneto 1100264 Apr  9 14:37 ./fpthread_make.so
```

### ldd Output

```
$ ldd fpthread_cmake.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe64f96000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb3604d0000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb36014e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb35ff38000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb35fd1b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb35f951000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb36092e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb35f648000)
$ ldd fpthread_make.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdd017a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcc32b6d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcc32950000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fcc325ce000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcc323b8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcc31fee000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcc32fcb000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcc31ce5000)
```

### Examples Makefile

```
FPTHREAD_HOME=../../
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -O0
PLIB = -lpthread
FPLIB = $(FPTHREAD_HOME)/libfpthread.so

#nvthread
INC_DIR = $(FPTHREAD_HOME)/include
SRC_DIR = $(FPTHREAD_HOME)/src

FPINCLUDE_DIRS = -I$(INC_DIR)
FPSRCS = $(SRC_DIR)/fprecovery.cpp

TARGETS=read-my-writes

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(TARGETS)

read-my-writes:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(FPINCLUDE_DIRS) $(FPSRCS) read-my-writes.c -o $@ -rdynamic $(FPLIB) -ldl

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGETS)

reset:
    rm -rf /mnt/ramdisk/fpthreads/*
    rm -f /tmp/fplib.crash
```

### LD_DEBUG Output

#### CMake

After building `libfpthread.so` with CMake (`cmake . -G 'Unix Makefiles'; make`):

```
$ LD_DEBUG=all ./read-my-writes
     64187: 
     64187: file=libfpthread.so [0];  needed by ./read-my-writes [0]
     64187: find library=libfpthread.so [0]; searching
     64187:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     64187:  search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib        (system search path)
     64187:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/lib/tls/x86_64/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/lib/tls/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/lib/x86_64/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/lib/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libfpthread.so
     64187:   trying file=/usr/lib/libfpthread.so
     64187: 
./read-my-writes: error while loading shared libraries: libfpthread.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

#### Makefile

After building `libfpthread.so` with the old Makefile (`make`):

```
$ LD_DEBUG=all ./read-my-writes
     63819: 
     63819: file=../..//libfpthread.so [0];  needed by ./read-my-writes [0]
     63819: file=../..//libfpthread.so [0];  generating link map
     63819:   dynamic: 0x00007f13c55f5b60  base: 0x00007f13c53b2000   size: 0x0000000000259c28
     63819:     entry: 0x00007f13c53cd2a0  phdr: 0x00007f13c53b2040  phnum:                  7
     63819: 
     63819: 
     63819: file=libstdc++.so.6 [0];  needed by ./read-my-writes [0]
     63819: find library=libstdc++.so.6 [0]; searching
     63819:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     63819:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
     63819: 
     63819: file=libstdc++.so.6 [0];  generating link map
     63819:   dynamic: 0x00007f13c53aad50  base: 0x00007f13c5030000   size: 0x0000000000381400
     63819:     entry: 0x00007f13c50b9d20  phdr: 0x00007f13c5030040  phnum:                  8
     63819: 
     63819: 
     63819: file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by ./read-my-writes [0]
     63819: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
     63819:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     63819:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     63819: 
     63819: file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
     63819:   dynamic: 0x00007f13c5029ba0  base: 0x00007f13c4c66000   size: 0x00000000003c99a0
     63819:     entry: 0x00007f13c4c86950  phdr: 0x00007f13c4c66040  phnum:                 10
     63819: 
     63819: 
     63819: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  needed by ../..//libfpthread.so [0]
     63819: find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
     63819:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     63819:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
     63819: 
     63819: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  generating link map
     63819:   dynamic: 0x00007f13c4c64d88  base: 0x00007f13c4a62000   size: 0x00000000002030f0
     63819:     entry: 0x00007f13c4a62da0  phdr: 0x00007f13c4a62040  phnum:                  7
     63819: 
     63819: 
     63819: file=libgcc_s.so.1 [0];  needed by ../..//libfpthread.so [0]
     63819: find library=libgcc_s.so.1 [0]; searching
     63819:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     63819:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
     63819: 
     63819: file=libgcc_s.so.1 [0];  generating link map
     63819:   dynamic: 0x00007f13c4a612b0  base: 0x00007f13c484c000   size: 0x0000000000215910
     63819:     entry: 0x00007f13c484ea70  phdr: 0x00007f13c484c040  phnum:                  6
     63819: 
     63819: 
     63819: file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  needed by ../..//libfpthread.so [0]
     63819: find library=libpthread.so.0 [0]; searching
     63819:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     63819:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
     63819: 
     63819: file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  generating link map
     63819:   dynamic: 0x00007f13c4846d50  base: 0x00007f13c462f000   size: 0x000000000021c428
     63819:     entry: 0x00007f13c46350b0  phdr: 0x00007f13c462f040  phnum:                  9
     63819: 
     63819: 
     63819: file=libm.so.6 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
     63819: find library=libm.so.6 [0]; searching
     63819:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     63819:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
     63819: 
     63819: file=libm.so.6 [0];  generating link map
     63819:   dynamic: 0x00007f13c462dd88  base: 0x00007f13c4326000   size: 0x00000000003080f8
     63819:     entry: 0x00007f13c432b600  phdr: 0x00007f13c4326040  phnum:                  7
     63819: 
...
```

Please note:

- It's the first time I'm using CMake, and I'm not too knowledgeable in Makefiles. Any sort of constructive comments are appreciated, even if not directly related to the question itself :-)
- Sorry for the terrible title; was unsure what to call it!

Comment: You show the code which creates `fpthread` library, but error message is about linking with it. How do you create `fpthread_cmake` and `fpthread_make` libraries?

Comment: They are the exact same library. I just renamed them for the sake of comparing them. `fpthread_cmake` was built via the `Makefile` generated by `cmake . -G 'Unix Makefiles'`. `fpthread_make` was built using the *old* Makefile.

Comment: One difference I see is you are not compiling with `-fPIC`.

Comment: The `-fPIC` flag is added by CMake when specifying `SHARED` in `add_library()`. I added the output of `cmake . -G 'Unix Makefiles'; make` in the question body for clarification :)

Comment: Can you try running the examples again after setting the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable to `all`? (See: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html#ENVIRONMENT)? Maybe you'll get some insights from the output?

Comment: Also, I can see three filenames being used for the same library (`fpthread{,_cmake,_make}`.so) in your question. I'm assuming you renamed them manually for clarity while prepping the post, but in the off chance there was a filename mixup there, it could worth double checking, perhaps?

Comment: Another thing: How do the examples load the shared library? Are they linked against it at build time, or do they dynamically load it using `dlopen`? In the latter case, you might want to try replacing `SHARED` with `MODULE` in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: And please remove the `add_definitions(-lpthread)` line. The pthread library is already added in the `target_link_libraries(fpthread Threads::Threads)` call.

Comment: @vre already done :-) had forgotten to clean it up.

Comment: @NicolasTisserand thanks! Didn't know about `LD_DEBUG`. Output of `LD_DEBUG` added to the question body. Examples use `dlopen`: they are compiled with `-rdynamic`. The Makefile used to compile the examples is also included in the question body.

Comment: It's weird to me why the output of `LD_DEBUG` differs. The path to the library is specified in the Makefile (?)

Comment: @NicolasTisserand also, there's only a single `libfpthread.so` file. The others were indeed just to compare them manually and they're not being used at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your issue, and have a potential solution. Try adding this to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set_property(TARGET fpthread PROPERTY NO_SONAME ON)
```

And rebuild `libfpthread.so`.

The reason why this happens is:

When an executable is linked with a shared object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the executable is run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared object specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file name given to the linker.

Excerpt from: https://linux.die.net/man/1/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd, under the `-soname` option documentation.

See also: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/NO_SONAME.html

Comment: Totally correct -- removing the `DT_SONAME` field fixes the issue. An alternative I guess is to include the library in a different more-standard way? Just wondering what you'd recommend :-)

Comment: Nice :) If that's possible, I would suggest integrating both the library and the examples in a single CMake build tree and use `target_link_libraries` so CMake can see the examples -> library dependency and do the right thing. You can keep separate directories as long as you call `add_subdirectory` first for the library directory, then for the examples directory from a top-level `CMakeLists.txt`. Good luck!

Comment: @joaomlneto: I don't quite understand you: In [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735023/translate-makefile-into-cmakelists-cannot-load-shared-library?noredirect=1#comment86487047_49735023) you say that you use `dlopen` for load the library at **runtime**. This answer implies, that you **link** with the library. What is truth?